# Nonlinear Random Effects Model Specification in R

Tags: nonlinear-regression

I have a dependent variable **w** with independent variable **x** representing time, which is clustered by variable **site**.  In addition, I have indicator variables for 3 time period: **i1, i2, i3**, which correspond to three distinct time periods along the timeline (separated by t1 and t2).  Since I want an overall fit, which evaluates the trends throughout the three time periods, I am trying to fit a nonlinear function (defined as **L3**) using slope estimates from as linear model fit like so:

```
L3<-function(x,alpha1,beta1,beta2,beta3) {
brk = c(t1,t2)
alpha2 <- alpha1 + beta1*brk[1]-beta2*brk[1]
alpha3 = alpha2 + beta2 * brk[2] - beta3*brk[2]
lebrk <- (x < brk[1])
gebrk <- (x > brk[2])
mdbrk <- (x > brk[1] & x < brk[2])

result <- rep(0,length(x))
result[lebrk] <- alpha1 + beta1*x[lebrk]
result[mdbrk] <- alpha2 + beta2*x[mdbrk]
result[gebrk] <- alpha3 + beta3*x[gebrk]
result
}

fit0 = lm(w ~ x + I(i2+i3)+I(x*(i2+i3))+ I(i3)+I(x*i3), data = wr_tx1)
summary(fit0)

alpha1 = fit0$coef[1]
    beta1 = fit0$coef[2]
beta2 = fit0$coef[2] + fit0$coef[4]
beta3 = fit0$coef[2] + fit0$coef[4] + fit0$coef[6]
fit1 <- nls(w ~ L3(x = x, alpha1, beta1, beta2, beta3)
        , data = wr_tx1
        , start = list(alpha1 = alpha1, beta1 = beta1, beta2 = beta2, beta3 = beta3)
        , control=nls.control(maxiter=100))
```

Since my data is clustered, however, I would like to include random effects at the site level using variable **site**.  I'm trying to figure out how to specify the NLME function to do this, but it seems to require a fixed effects argument even though I'm not concerned with any fixed effects right now.  Alternatively, I could include a fixed effect variable for the treatment group that each site is in (variable called **tx**), but it is unclear how to specific the NLME function in that case either.

To try incorporate the fixed effects, I have tried the following, but I get an error:

```
wr$tx = as.factor(wr$tx)
fit2 = nlme(w ~ L3(x = x, alpha1, beta1, beta2, beta3)
        , random = alpha1 + beta1 + beta2 + beta3 ~ 1 | site
        , fixed = tx ~ 1
        , data = wr
        , start = list(alpha1 = alpha1, beta1 = beta1, beta2 = beta2, beta3 = beta3))

Error in nlme.formula(w ~ L3(x = x, alpha1, beta1, beta2, beta3), random = alpha1 
  'start' must have a component called 'fixed'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I happened to get the same error message:
`Error in nlme.formula(… : 'start' must have a component called 'fixed'`

By looking at the description of the argument ‘start’ in the R help for nlme, I learnt that it is a simple syntax error in the start argument:
Type `start = c(…,…)` instead of `start = list(…, …)` as in nls, then it should work.